VS C# Namespace not found / recognized / greyed out. Have you created your Project .resx Resource File yet? required needed why Visual Studio
I have about 20 Projects in my Solution.
I have my own library namespace which I call "Marcus" which I make my Default Namespace in Project.Properties.Application.
Over the years I have developed some inconsistency in how I begin my program code, I have found that I have been simply adding my Project file to the Marcus namespace or the Marcus namespace was not visible for some apparent reason.
Perhaps due to an update, tonight, I have been presented with this problem on many previously compiling Projects.

I have tonight determined that these Projects did not have their Resource File ".resx" created from the Project.Properties.Resources tab page.

Indeed this has been my problem, I can now start my program code as I would like to.
But why? Why do i need to create this empty Resource File for my namespace to be visible in my main() project file? This has undermined much of my Visual Studio programming confidence over the years.
I can provide a short video of this issue being resolved if no one believes this to be true and can provide me with an explanation.
Searches online did not provide information required towards the resolution found.

Open the csproj file with a text editor and see if the reference is any of the command in the project file.

VS IDE should be able to identify my namespace without having to create a Default Resource File. This is not an obvious IDE dependency.

it is only creating the resource file because it is part of the instructions in the csproj file.  We need to understand what instruction in the csproj is creating the resource file.
